# only two digits allowed after decimal asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox where the user must not be able to enter more than two digits after a decimal.How do I do this without using javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: RegularExpressionValidator as mentioned below is nice option but what validation expression you might want to give an example of valid and invalid inputs to give your exact regex.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the [`MaxLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength) property of the textbox, but that doesn't have any notion of whether or where the decimal point is.

You could also use a `CustomValidator` and check the inputted number on the server via the [`ServerValidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.servervalidate) event.  But this will require going to the server to check the value (i.e. it will initially look like your form allows users to input invalid numbers).

You should also be able use to a `RegularExpressionValidator`, depending on your exact globalization requirements, which will use JavaScript on the client to provide immediate feedback:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="NumberTextBox" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="NumberTextBox" 
                                ValidationExpression="\d+(?:(?:\.|,)\d{1,2})?" />
```

If you want the immediate feedback to the user, you'll need to use a JavaScript based solution.

Comment: RegularExpressionValidator is probably simpler.  Also, while it uses JavaScript, the ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit MaskedEdit control at least feels more like a server control than writing your own jQuery. ;-)

Comment: How do we check using a Server validate event?

Comment: @lisa, in the same way that you'd wire-up to a `Click` event of a `Button`, wire-up to the `ServerValidate` event of a `CustomValidator`, and then set `args.IsValid` depending on the validity of the input.

Comment: The ValidationExpression="\d+(?:\.|,)?\d{0,2}" has several flaws. e.g. 15. or 15, will be pass the validation.

Comment: @bdukes: Yep! That looks good but as you said OP still needs to adjust it as per other constraints, if any, and globalization requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cause the textbox to stop accepting text after two decimal places without directly or indirectly using javascript. (This is sometimes called an input mask).

You can, however, allow the user to enter free-form text and validate the text upon postback on the server.  You can either automatically round the number for them, or return an error message to the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to prevent the user from entering more than two digits after the decimal point, you'll need to use JavaScript or a server control that implements the JavaScript for you.

However, may make more sense to allow them to enter any number of digits and then catch it on validation (or just round to two digits).